# Can we upload a django project on cpanel and run it if the cpanel doesnt have a terminal?

Tags: django, cpanel

I got the basic hosting plan from godaddy. Most tutorials on youtube are trash. So can we use a cpanel which doesn't have terminal to run a django project? and should we include the venv folder while we upload?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GoDaddy economy plan supports wsgi applications, but check with their support.